# QTcpSocket doesn't read everything

Tags: qt, sockets, encryption

I am trying to use cryptopp with QTcpSocket, what i do is encrypt a username on my client side, send it through a TCPSocket, and decrypt it server side. Here is my problem, QTcpSocket doesn't read all the message, as you can see server side i am expecting to receive several packets for one cipher, read method says the whole message was read but in my char*, i don't see it all really.... Here is my code sending the cipher :

```
char size[5];
sprintf(size,"%d{",crypted_mess.size());

int written = 0;
written = socket->write(size);
written = socket->write(crypted_mess.c_str(),crypted_mess.size()+ 1);
socket->waitForBytesWritten(crypted_mess.size());
string recovered = T.discryptor(crypted_mess) ;
```

and my code to decrypt it (works fine client side without sending the message) :

```
    if(paquet_missing_size == 0) {
        current_message->clear();
        was_read = socket->read(start_message,1000);

        int message_start = 0;
        while(start_message[message_start]!= '{')
            message_start++;

        char *size_total_string;
        size_total_string = (char*)malloc (message_start * sizeof (char));

        for(int j = 0 ;j < message_start;j++  ){
            size_total_string[j] = start_message[j];
        }

        size_total_string[message_start] = '\0' ;
        paquet_missing_size = atoi(size_total_string);
        memcpy(read,start_message+message_start+1,was_read - message_start);
    }
    else
        was_read = socket->read(read,1000);

    // add the read thing to the current_message
    if(was_read <= paquet_missing_size) {
        current_message->append(read, was_read);
        paquet_missing_size -= was_read;
    } else {
        current_message->append(read, paquet_missing_size);
        paquet_missing_size = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this purpose you should always use a QByteArray with a QDataStream in order to pass the size of the message first then your message.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did the trick ! i will post the code answering later !

Comment: You should add that the reason for this is that TCP/IP is a streaming protocol. It only guarantees that the bytes will get there, not that they will get there in any particularly sized chunks. It's perfectly acceptable for the bytes to come in one at a time.